# How to invoke a JSF backing bean method from a non-faces request?

Tags: jsf

We have a requirement to replace our current login, for a web-application written in JSF using single sign-on. Currently our login.jsp invokes the authenticate method on a backing bean to achieve this and perform additional role validations. Now authentication will be done by my single sign-on server, but how do i invoke the authenticate method on the backing bean to perform the role validations

Answer (score 2):

Set request parameters as managed properties and use the `@PostConstruct` annotation to execute some code immediately after bean construction and managed property setting.

You can set GET or POST request parameters as managed properties as follows:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>bean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>mypackage.Bean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>name1</property-name>
        <value>#{param.name1}</value>
    </managed-property>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>name2</property-name>
        <value>#{param.name2}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

Or if you're already on JSF 2.0, then you can just use `@ManagedProperty`:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{param.name1}")
private String name1;

@ManagedProperty(value="#{param.name2}")
private String name2;
```

Those parameters will be set when the enduser fires a GET or POST request with a `name1=value1&name2=value2` query string. The `#{param.name1}` EL expression basically stands for the result of `request.getParameter("name1")`.

Now create a `@PostConstruct` method like follows:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    if (name1 != null && name2 != null) {
        // Both request parameters are been set. Do your thing here!
    }
}
```

Comment: hello baslusc, but how would you invoke the creation of the bean? Since the @PostConstruct will only be used once the bean is created. Since bean creation is invoked when the request is the faces request but in this case the request is the non-faces request.

Comment: @Tarun: If it's a non-faces request, then you need to look for a non-faces solution. A simple servlet or maybe a filter.

Comment: thats exactly what I meant(a simple servlet),  But question seems to be off-target as it states "How to invoke a JSF backing bean method from a non-faces request?" so it's talking about JSF bean  being invoked from a non faces request. The concept explained in your answer involves invocation of the JSF bean. But since in the question it was written "non-faces" request so I couldn't comprehend your answer in context of question.

Comment: @Tarun: refactor the bean's original code into a separate class which you import/use in both the servlet and backing bean.